# In R, is there a way to filter based on a variable what has "_" in it's name?

Tags: r

I am working with a large data name "BRFSS2015" and my assignment requires that I find the average "Number of Days Mental Health Not Good" for those in Pennsylvania who have numeric data? I started by using the following code but an error keeps appearing because the "_" in _STATE will not work:

```r
BRFSS2015%>%
  filter(_STATE == "Pennsylvania")
```

> **Error: unexpected input in:
> "BRFSS2015%>%
> filter(_"**

I have also tried backticks and gsub() on it but to no avail. Please help.

Comment: Please include a sample of your date using `dput(head(BRFSS2015))`.

Comment: Use backquote on `_STATE` as the beginning character is unusual

Comment: `> ?'`' ` takes you to `Quotes`, and in Names and Identifiers "`Identifiers consist of a sequence of letters, digits, the period
     (‘.’) and the underscore.  They must not start with a digit nor
     underscore,`', and these types of head scratches come with every data wrangling you'll do. Welcome to Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to surround the variable name with backticks. Here is a small example:

```r
library(dplyr)

tb = tibble(value = rnorm(5), "_state" = letters[1:5])

tb
#> # A tibble: 5 x 2
#>     value `_state`
#>     <dbl> <chr>   
#> 1 -0.769  a       
#> 2  0.273  b       
#> 3 -1.32   c       
#> 4 -0.0795 d       
#> 5 -0.701  e

# Without backticks
tb %>% 
  filter(_state == "a")

#> Error: unexpected input in:
#> "tb %>% 
#>   filter(_"

# With backticks
tb %>% 
  filter(`_state` == "a")
#> # A tibble: 1 x 2
#>    value `_state`
#>    <dbl> <chr>   
#> 1 -0.769 a
```

Or avoid this issue by renaming the variable, e.g. with `rename`.

```r
tb %>% 
  rename(state = `_state`)
#> # A tibble: 5 x 2
#>    value state
#>    <dbl> <chr>
#> 1 -0.573 a    
#> 2 -1.43  b    
#> 3 -1.26  c    
#> 4 -0.313 d    
#> 5  1.06  e
```

More information on these *syntactic names* are available in the documentation for quotes

```r
# To view, use ?`"`
```

> Identifiers consist of a sequence of letters, digits, the period (.)
> and the underscore ...
>
> Such identifiers are also known as syntactic names and may be used
> directly in R code. The preferred quote is the backtick (`), and deparse
> will normally use it, but under many circumstances single or double
> quotes can be used (as a character constant will often be converted to
> a name).

<sup>Created on 2022-04-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: `janitor::clean_names()` could also do the renaming here for you, if you want it for more columns

Comment: mhovd, THANK YOU SO MUCH for your thorough answer! The rename() solved it. I'm new at this so again, thank you!